# How to copy my project dependecies to remote server in maven?

Tags: maven-3, remote-server, maven-dependency-plugin

How can I copy all the dependencies to remote server? I've tried below one but it will be useful if we want to copy dependencies to our local path.

Is this possible to move all my project dependencies to remote path?

Comment: This is more a task for puppet, chef or may be Ant scripting instead of Maven. Maven is a build tool not a deployment tool or may be installation into test/prod etc. The best would be to create a tar.gz or zip archive which contains everything and transfer it to the appropriate server.

Answer (score 2):

The [wagon-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) allows you to do that. It supports HTTP, FTP, SSH/SCP and WebDAV. To upload all your dependencies, you first need to copy them to a directory with the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) (goal [copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)). In a second step you could use the wagon plugin's upload goal to copy them to your remote location.